# Using .swc's within a Flex Library Project

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, builder, swc

I'm trying to set up a production environment for about 10 related assets. Certain elements, visual and otherwise, are going to be shared between the 10 assets. I'm treating each one as its own Pure AS3 project in Flash Builder 4.

Each asset has an associated .fla which is outputting a .swc into the libs folder for that asset - the final compilation is going to be done via ant, and the top-level source is the main .as file in each Flash Builder project.

Because certain elements are shared between multiple assets, I've created a Flex Library Project in my workspace. This library project has a /src folder with a standard structure, as well as a /lib/ folder in which I'm sticking, for instance, greensock's TweenLite.

In addition to the source code and third-party .swc, the Library project also has an FLA which exports a .swc into the /lib/ folder.

Here's the problem: I'm not able to see library exports from that .swc in my related projects. In theory, every class I export from the library of the Flex Library Project's .fla should be compiled into the library project's .swc. I'm finding that this is not the case, and I'm not clear why.

I'm going to continue digging, but I wanted to throw this up here in case anyone else has run into these issues. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: So apparently my greensock .swc isn't being compiled into the final output either. Yesterday it was. I'm not sure what has changed. I guess my question, distilled down, is this: how can I make sure that .swc files included in the build path for my Flex Library Project have all of their classes included in the final .swc that the FLP generates?

EDIT2: I've discovered a sort of a terrible workaround. Right now I've created a single class in my src folder and I'm declaring anything that I want included from any of my .swc's - so for instance, public var tweenLite:TweenLite, public var logo:Logo, etc. I find that if I declare it in one of my source files then I'm able to access it in a related project. Importing it alone is not enough - this means that I would have to manually declare every class I want access to. There must be a better way. What am I missing?

Comment: What kind of Link Type is set for your swc in Library project properties `Flex Library Build Path > Library Path` tab? Is it `Merged into code`?

Comment: Yes. I've just figured out a workaround, about to update my post - but it's still a PITA.  But yes, "Merged into code" is currently selected. The other option, "Use Default(external)", had been selected - it didn't work correctly with either.

Comment: BTW you're right, import directive doesn't include imported class into compilation. But you haven't to include (declare) all the classes from swc. If all the classes there are coupled you can declare only main class which refers to each others by the chain. And you can link classes using more simple syntax than declaring every single class: `private static var linking:Array = [Class1, Class2];`

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced some issues that are down the same line where we were getting Class A from SDK swc 1 and Class B from SDK swc 2 (blendMode error results), in the end we had to guarantee all our dependencies were compiled with a particular version of the SDK (also not fun).  I think it sounds like you want a library that contains the source from all the other libraries that your new library depends on.

Basically each swc is a catalog file and the ActionScript Bytecode (ABC) for the ActionScript(AS) files compressed into a zip, so you'd want it to merge both of those parts into a single swc.

Using Runtime Shared Libraries (RSL) means instead of pulling the bytecode from the swc and including it in your swf during compile time it'll load the swc (called a swz when packaged this way) at run-time.  The disadvantage is it stores all the classes into the swz as opposed to only pulling the bytecode for the AS you need when done at compile time.  So going with linking via RSL should get you the result you want i believe but you'll have to generate the swz files from your library.  You may still end up having to do something ridiculous like having references to everything you want in your swz (from the other swcs) but I believe you should be able to resolve the issue this way somehow... I'm continuing to look around for a better solution and will edit this if I find one:

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/creating-runtime-shared-libraries/

Edit 1:

Also found this:

compc -source-path ../mycomponents/components/local 
    -include-classes CustomCellRendererComponent 
    -directory=true 
    -debug=false
    -output ../libraries/CustomCellRenderer

From this page:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_01.html#168690

A couple of thoughts on this too as I've been looking around, 1 this is going to be horribly inefficient in terms of space, hence all the work to only include the classes you're using, 2 if using the method above I would probably write a java app that'll traverse a projects folders for all the Class names so I could have it generate a listing of all classes in the project space.

Thanks for hearing out my thoughts (still a WIP :),

Shaun

Comment: Thanks Shaun, sounds like you're on the right track. I will be diving back into this this afternoon, so we'll see what it gets me!